# Union All does not return the same number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query that uses `union all`. When i run the following query only one row with `NULL` value is returned (the value is null because there is no data for that time period). The expectation was that 2 rows with null would be returned. What gives?

```
SELECT 
  SUM(val) AS GA 
FROM
  mytable 
WHERE region = 'someRegion' 
  AND ACTIVITY_MTH BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30' 

UNION
ALL 

SELECT 
  quota 
FROM
  budgetTable 
WHERE sales_id = 'someRegion' 
  AND start_date = '2014-04-01' 
  AND metric_id = 1
```

Comment: I think you are not understanding mysql. There is a difference between union and join. I think you want to join here (or left/right join).

Comment: What do you get when you run each half of the query on its own?

Comment: each part on its own returns 1 row with `NULL`. `NOTE` that if the response values are not NULL then 2 rows are returned as expected.

Comment: changing `quota` to `sum(quota)` returns 2 rows as expected.